# How to get headline and button/link inline

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have no idea how i can get h1 and the button inline. I have tried everything

```html
    <h1 id="h1">Text</h1>
 <a href="#" id="Btn" class="button">Btn</a>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```html
<h1 id="h1" style="float:left;margin:0">H1</h1>
<a style="float:left" href="#" id="Btn" class="button">Btn</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet

```css
.parent{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
            <div class="parent>
            
            <h1 id="h1">h1</h1>
            <a href="#" id="Btn" class="button">Btn</a>
            
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Css code:

```
h1,a{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If elements have a parent just add `display: inline-block` to parent. If not you have to add `display: inline-block` to each element.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as that:

```
#h1, #Btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle /* the type of alignment you're looking for */
}
```